# Unemployed duplicant still requiring high morale

Tags: oxygen-not-included

I have a duplicant in Oxygen Not Included that is suffering from stress because he requires a high morale due to his (former job). However, I removed him from that job, but he is still requiring high morale.

Is the morale requirement permanent once you give a duplicant a job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is permanent.

> - Morale will replace Food and Decor Expectations. As Duplicants gain training, you'll have to improve the colony around them
>
>   - Added Morale modifiers for using recreation buildings, proper bathrooms/mess halls/bedrooms, and food eaten
>   - New tiers of rooms added
>   - Massage Table is now a medical/stress item rather than a recreation item

The important bit to note here is the 'gain training'. This means that when a Duplicant masters a job or gets trained in an advanced job, it will modify their expectations about the colony. You can see this in the Duplicant details panel.

Reference, [expressive update patch notes](https://forums.kleientertainment.com/game-updates/oni-alpha/279457-r525/).

Your best bet to solve the problem would be to improve the decor scores in your colony, and improve the quality of the food you are providing.

Comment: ... or kill the duplicant with the morale problem. BTW what is the "Duplicant details panel"?

Comment: @TylerDurden If you click on a Duplicant, a details window will display.